# SQL Server Select query returning records twice in a table

Tags: sql-server

I am using the following query to get the top 10 companies from a table:

```
Select Top 10 CompanyName 
From CompanyMaster 
Where LiveProductFlag = 1 
Order By Display_Priority asc
```

It is returning records like this.

```
CompanyName
------------
First Company
Second Company
First Company
Second COmpany
Third Company
Third Company
Fourth Company
Fourth Company
Fifth Company
Fifth Company
```

I checked records and I don't have duplicate records. `Select Distinct` doesn't work. Tried all possible solutions after googling without any success.

Thanks.

Comment: It's difficult to tell exactly what you want, but I'm guessing you want 10 distinct company names ordered by the companies that have the lowest display_priority, in which case you might consider something like `SELECT TOP 10 CompanyName FROM CompanyMaster WHERE LiveProductFlag = 1 GROUP BY CompanyName ORDER BY MIN(Display_Property)` or something like that.

Comment: can you share your information_schema of the table with few sample records.

Answer (score 0):

You can run a simple count on your group field query as follows to doublecheck your assumption.

```
Select 
    CompanyName,
    DuplicateCount=COUNT(*)
From 
    CompanyMaster 
Where 
    LiveProductFlag = 1 
GROUP BY
     CompanyName
HAVING
    COUNT(*) > 1
ORDER BY
    COUNT(*) DESC
```